# Exit terminal after executing a command from .xbindkeysrc

Tags: bash, shell, key-bindings, gnome-terminal, openconnect

I'm trying to bind a command to a key using .xbindkeysrc, namely this command retrieves a password from keepassxc, and echoes it as stdin to an openconnect (for VPN connection) command, and finally closes the terminal. The following does all of this, and it works:

```
psswd=`keepassxc-cli show -sa password path/to/MYKEEPASS.kdbx MY_ENTRY` ; echo $psswd | sudo openconnect --background --protocol=gp https://my.url --user=MYUSERNAME --passwd-on-stdin ; exit
```

However, this wouldn't work as a command in .xbindkeysrc, it needs to be executed in a terminal, which can be done by putting the previous code between `"$()"` as follows (again, this works), BUT without the "`; exit`" final bit (it does not work with it), therefore the terminal is not closed after running the full command.

```
gnome-terminal -e "$(psswd=`keepassxc-cli show -sa password path/to/MYKEEPASS.kdbx MY_ENTRY` ; echo $psswd | sudo openconnect --background --protocol=gp https://my.url --user=MYUSERNAME --passwd-on-stdin)"
```

**Q1: How can I tell the terminal to close after executing the full command?**

In addition, this simpler syntax (within `""`) is understood by .xbindkeysrc:

```
"gnome-terminal -e "sudo openconnect --protocol=gp https://my.url --user=MYUSERNAME""
```

but simply adding `""` to the full command is not enough for .xbindkeysrc to run it when I press the bound key; this leads to my 2nd question:

**Q2: How can I integrate the full command in .xbindkeysrc?**

Thanks a lot

---

EDIT: after using [Grisha Levit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072229/grisha-levit)'s answer:

```
"gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'pass=$(keepassxc-cli show -a password my_keepass_DB my_ENTRY) && printf "%s\n" "$pass" | sudo openconnect --background --protocol=gp https://my.url --user=my_NAME --passwd-on-stdin'"
```

there is an problem with vpnc-script, shown in lines 2,5-7:

[image: Lines 2,5-7 are showing an error]

The bit without the `gnome-terminal --` does work:

```
sh -c 'pass=$(keepassxc-cli show -a password my_keepass_DB my_ENTRY) && printf "%s\n" "$pass" | sudo openconnect --background --protocol=gp https://my.url --user=my_NAME --passwd-on-stdin'
```

but this wouldn't work in .xbindkeysrc

Comment: What version of `gnome-terminal` is it? Mine gives the warning `Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.`. That said, do you know about `sh -c 'echo foo; echo bar | cat'`? You can probably use this kind of "inline" script in .xbindkeysrc

Comment: Why are you wrapping your command in `$(...)`? Do you really expect that long pipeline to output the name of a command to execute??

Comment: @tripleee I'm only wrapping the first part:  pass=$(keepassxc-cli show -a password my_keepass_DB my_ENTRY) ...

Comment: Your question shows the command line `gnome-terminal -e "$(psswd=\`keepassxc-cli show -sa password path/to/MYKEEPASS.kdbx MY_ENTRY\` ; echo $psswd | sudo openconnect --background --protocol=gp https://my.url --user=MYUSERNAME --passwd-on-stdin)"`

Comment: @tripleee I am using the command suggested in the EDIT note at the end of my post

Comment: Requiring a terminal for something which is essentially a GUI anyway seems roundabout. Can you use a dialog utility like `zenity` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should pass the command to run in `gnome-terminal` as positional parameters rather than using the `-e` option. (i.e. `gnome-terminal -- cmd arg...`)
- You can't use shell syntax directly, it must go through e.g. `sh -c`.

So the command could be like:

```bash
gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'pass=$(keepassxc-cli show -a password DB ENTRY) && printf "%s\n" "$pass" | sudo openconnect --background --passwd-on-stdin …'
```

If that works, it should exit the terminal after starting the `openconnect` command so no `exit` needed.

---

There's nothing special about this being in .xbindkeysrc -- just wrap the command above in double quotes.

Comment: Surprisingly, the double quotes do not need escaping or any special treatment in the .xbinkeysrc file. I was originally going to suggest piping the password but then thought it's probably a good idea to capture it first and only continue if that part worked instead of piping an empty string in case the KeePass command failed

Comment: Thanks, it is running but just at the end it "exits abnormally", please check screenshot in my edit (sorry, I had to to a screenshot since it was happening too fast for being able to copy the text)

Comment: That seems like an issue specific to `openconnect --background` running in a terminal that's closed -- probably better if you can narrow down a separate question for that without the xkeybindrc file.