# openconnect fails to keep running in the background in a terminal that's closed

Tags: linux, bash, key-bindings, gnome-terminal, openconnect

This is a spin-off from [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75869910/exit-terminal-after-executing-a-command-from-xbindkeysrc/75871494?noredirect=1#comment133843529_75871494).

This command retrieves a password from keepassxc, prints it as stdin to an `openconnect` (for VPN connection) command, and the process goes to the background.

```
sh -c 'pass=$(keepassxc-cli show -a password my_keepass_DB my_ENTRY) && printf "%s\n" "$pass" | sudo openconnect --background --protocol=gp https://my.url --user=my_NAME --passwd-on-stdin'
```

Now, I would like to bind this command to a key using .xbindkeysrc, for which we need to prepend `gnome-terminal --` (and double-quote the whole line):

```
"gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'pass=$(keepassxc-cli show -a password my_keepass_DB my_ENTRY) && printf "%s\n" "$pass" | sudo openconnect --background --protocol=gp https://my.url --user=my_NAME --passwd-on-stdin'"
```

But it seems that `openconnect --background` fails to keep running in a terminal that's closed; namely there is an problem with vpnc-script, shown in lines 2,5-7:

[image]

**Question**: How to run this command within a terminal that exits after the command is run, so that openconnect keeps running in the background?

Comment: put a `&` at the end?

Comment: No, none of these work: `... --passwd-on-stdin $'"`, `... --passwd-on-stdin' & "`, nor `... --passwd-on-stdin'" &`

Comment: You get an EPIPE when you read or write to any file descriptors open to a dead terminal. Use `</dev/null >my.log 2>&1 & disown -h "$!"` and that replaces all of stidn, stdout, and stderr. No file descriptors open, and the disown prevents the SIGHUP from being forwarded by the shell. (You'll want to change `sh -c` to `bash -c` to make `disown` available, though).

Comment: Mind, you don't even strictly need the `disown` in the first place for a shell started with `sh -c` or `bash -c`, since HUP forwarding is only on-by-default for _interactive_ shells; generally the redirection is enough.

Comment: That said, for a program that needs to prompt the user for passwords, can write informative logs, &c., and that generally makes sense to run interactively, in practice I'd probably use `screen` or `tmux` instead to have a "terminal" that stays running and can be reattached to even after you close the gnome-terminal it was started inside of.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried `gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'pass=... | sudo openconnect --background ... --passwd-on-stdin < /dev/null > /tmp/openconnect.log 2>&1'` and it returns `fgets (stdin): No such file or directory`. Also tried variations without the `< /dev/null` part (it returns SIGHUP error again), and with `bash -c '... disown -h "$!"'` (doesn't do anything)

Comment: I have a lot of trouble believing "No such file or directory", unless you're running in a chroot or container that doesn't have `/dev/null`. Though `--passwd-on-stdin </dev/null` won't work for obvious reasons if you expect there to actually be a password read. For `--passwd-on-stdin` to succeed, you have to be attached to stdin. `nohup` breaks that attachment, just like `</dev/null` does. If you need to be attached to read a password, let openconnect detach itself (which given `--background` it presumably supports) instead of trying to forcefully detach it from the parent.